# Is using an assignment operator in a function argument undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, operator-precedence

I found some code similar to this in an example my university tutor wrote.

```
int main(){
    int a=3;
    int b=5;
    std::vector<int>arr;
    arr.push_back(a*=b);
    std::cout<<arr[0]<<std::endl;
}
```

Is there a well-defined behaviour for this? Would `arr[0]` be 3 or 15 (or something else entirely)?
Visual Studio outputs 15, but I have no idea if that's how other compilers would respond to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before push_back is executed, the expression passed as argument will need to be computed. So what is the value of `a *= b`. Well it will always be `a * b` and also the new value of `a` will be set to that one.

Answer (score 3):

It's valid and works as you expect.

The expression is first evaluated and the result is "returned".

```
auto& temp = (a*=b);
arr.push_back(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of an expression with the compound assignment operator is the value of the left operand after the assignment.
So the code your showed is valid. Moreover in C++ (opposite to C) the result is an `lvalue`. So you may even write :)

```
arr.push_back( ++( a *= b ) );
```

In this case the next statement outputs `16`.:)